# Normal boot hangs on "Scanning for BTRFS files systems" after conversion from ext4

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, mount, btrfs

I have a headless server with an installation of Ubuntu 16.04. The default installation comes with an ext4 file system and reinstalling it from scratch is not possible, but I need the snapshot and subvolume capabilities. Using the rescue mode I converted `/` to btrfs. `/boot` is still ext4. I used [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-convert-an-ext3-ext4-root-file-system-to-btrfs-on-ubuntu-12.10-p2) as basis for the conversion.

The system did not boot! I have checked `/etc/fstab` and the mounts are correct. The server runs fine out of a chroot from the rescue disk.

---

I replicated the system and the steps taken in a local setup and performed the same conversion. I can now see that it hangs on "Scanning for Btrfs file systems", however it boots in rescue mode just fine and I can mount all partitions.

---

- How would I figure out why grub/Ubuntu seemingly is not finding the file system or stuck on scanning?
- Can I uninstall btrfs-tools as suggested in the other answers, even though I have a btrfs file system?